# Guest has mini freezes on Virtual Box

Tags: 10.10, virtualbox, freeze

Ubuntu 10.10 starts to have mini freezes every 2 seconds. If I am typing in any sort of input (for example the terminal or a text field in Firefox or a text editor), I can type a few letters and then the entire OS will freeze for about half a second and I will lose focus. I can then (if I'm quick) click back into the input and continuing typing before it freezes again.

This will continue until I try and do something like close Firefox, kill/start a process from the terminal or save my work from a text editor. At that point the entire system locks up and I have to force the virtual machine to close.

I only experience this if Ubuntu has been running for some time with a minimum of roughly 1 hour. I am running Ubuntu as a guest on Virtual box (version 4.0.4) from inside a Windows 7 host. Windows itself does not freeze or become inoperable at all during this time.

The only thing I can do is to restart Ubuntu and get as much work done before it decides to freeze again. Very frustrating.

What steps can I take to solve or further troubleshoot this problem?

### Update

Following [Takkat's instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33649/guest-has-mini-freezes-on-virtual-box/33671#33671), I was already doing the following:

- Had VT-x/AMD-V enabled
- Latest version of virtual box
- Guest additions installed
- Disabled 3D acceleration
- Enabled nested paging
- RAM set to under half of total system RAM (3GB out of 8GB)

In addition, I did the following:

- Disabled screensaver in Ubuntu
- Reduced cores from 2 to 1
- Increased Video memory

This seems to have completely fixed the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Freezes are generally hard to debug because your system becomes unresponsive then. This is even more the case when the cause of this could be anywhere

- a problem of the host OS (Windows 7),
- the guest OS (Ubuntu 10.10),
- or from Virtual Box.

---

From your descriptions we can only guess what might be the cause. In your case the system slows down before freezing, indicating problems in memory management, or from applications that eat up the CPU power you gave your virtual environment.

In the Ubuntu guest you can find out if an application causes this by running `top` in a terminal (or if you prefer a GUI in *System -> Administration -> System Monitor -> Processes*) to list CPU and memory usage of individual processes.

Other valuable informations on problems, or error messages from applications can also be found in the .log files that can be viewed with *System -> Administration -> Log File Viewer*.

If you had suspicious findings there don't hesitate and edit your question to include these informations.

---

Sometimes it can help to increase the performance and stability of the guest OS with different settings (most can be done in the Virtual Box Manager GUI after a shut down of the guest OS):

- **disable screensaver in the guest OS**
- **enable VT-x/AMD-V (if your host system  can do this)**
- **regularly update Virtual Box to current stable version**
- **install [Guest Additions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-virtual-box)**
- disable 3D acceleration
- increase video memory
- allow more RAM
- but avoid to allow more than 50% of total system RAM
- use one CPU core only
- enable or disable Nested Paging
- try using another audio driver (or disable audio)

Settings in bold are recommended in any case. The other points are suggestions on what you can try out to improve the performance of your virtual Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same issue after upgrading Virtualbox. The linux hosts freeze after the host when into power mode savings (I suspect there is an issue with Vbox and host OS power mode). I could only see the display and switch between a couple of applications after several attempts. But the linux guest became completely unresponsive. Windows host did not present any issues.

As a host I use a Windows 10 with 16 GB RAM, Virtualbox 5.1. Corresponding guest additions version.  Ubuntu 64 bits guest with 2 GB of RAM.

Tried the following with no avail:

- Changed number of CPUs, nested paging, disabled audio, and problem persisted
- Then following some old Vbox posts, I disabled sharing folders with host  OS, changed SATA controller to IDE controller. Problem continued.
- Installed extension pack. And started again with changes in CPUs, nested page, disabled folder sharing, etc. Problem persisted.
- Increased/decreased guest memory. Problem continued.
- Disabled/enabled NAT in network. No solution.
- Disconnected guest from network. Problem persisted.

**My solution:** I went back to 5.0. Problem solved. I haven't seen any bug report yet, but it appears that the 5.1 branch has some issues with Linux guests.

I currently use:

- Host Windows 10. 16 GB RAM.
- VBOX 5.0.26 with user additions.
- Ubuntu 64 bits. 2GB RAM, 2 processors, HD with SATA controller
- No video acceleration
- Both bridge / NAT networking work well.
- Screensaver in the linux guest works well, but I recommend disabling it.