# Problems running 64bit Virtual Machines in VBox even with a 64-bit OS

Tags: 64-bit, virtualbox, kubuntu

So I'm running Kubuntu 12.10 x64:

```
uname -v -p  #29-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 19 10:26:51 UTC 2012 x86_64
```

and Virtual Box 4.2 installed from the VBox repositories.

Any time I try to install a 64-bit OS as a guest the install fails and crashes w/ a kernel panic on Ubuntu or bombs in Windows 7 before it will boot.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Possibly related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/128830/amd64-virtual-machine-in-virtualbox and http://askubuntu.com/questions/33649/guest-has-mini-freezes-on-virtual-box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

64-bit guest should be supported, even on a 32-bit Host.

But do check the requirements and see if anything is missed out, make sure: VT-x/AMD-V is enabled in BIOS.

Also check the docs:
https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#intro-64bitguests

If you can paste the error message (Kernel Panic/BSOD?), we can assist better;-)

Comment: Thanks for this... Double checekd and everything was set, not quite sure but I unchecked all the settings and rechecked them and it worked.

Thanks for the advice and helping out